# .show() not working properly (no animation, no further code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I want a top banner to ease in as soon as the website is loaded. I use JQuery to do that task, but the show() function doesn't work as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#job').show(2000, function() {
    $('#cross').click(function() {
      $('#job').hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.job-banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #333;
  display: none;
}

.job-banner:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="job" class="job-banner">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

But that just shows up the div instantly without any animation and the code that should execute after the animation doesn't work as well. I tried to put an alert inside the code block that should execute after the .show() but nothing.

Is there another way of achieving that or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Because show/hide does not only change the display property, but also the opacity. So you have to set that to 0 too.

Comment: I added your code to an executable snippet where it appears to work fine. I would suggest that this problem is caused by some other CSS in your page which is affecting the element. Try using the DOM inspector to see what styles are applied.

Comment: @MauriceNino that's not the case

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are right it works without too. Didn't know. But AFAIK it changes opacity, height, width, display and whatnot. Not only display.

Comment: That's true, but it does it automatically. You wouldn't need to change your CSS to handle it.

Comment: Better use transitions. Because jQuery cause laggs on iOS devices. (It uses javascript timeouts + loops to change styles)

Comment: @Sergej Thanks for that suggestion! Is it possible to trigger the CSS transition as soon as the website is loaded?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Strange, I inspected the DOM and couldn't find any interference. Could that nested p be a problem when translated from SCSS to CSS?

Comment: It works as expected in your question. What's the problem?

Comment: Are you getting any jquery errors in your console?

Comment: Yes, you can add the css class that starts the transition, when the documents loads.

Comment: @raxerz No errors in the console.

Comment: @Sergej I tried that and exactly the same problem. Appears instantly but nothing more :/

Comment: You should add transition in the present class. The added class must add only animation.

Comment: for example: `.baseClass { width: 0; opacity: 0; height: 0; transition: 2s; }` `.animationClass { width: 100px; height: 100px; opacity: 1; }`

Answer (score 0):

@Sergej Thanks, that did the trick. I just needed to also declare opacity and now I have a css transition instead which is called by JQuery.

So for the CSS:

```
job-banner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #333;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#job').addClass('visible');
});
```

Comment: visibility doesn't have transition, so you can remove it from transition property. keep only opacity.